# How to add the width of elements inside an each statement to an array?

Tags: javascript, svelte

So I have a component that accepts a string array as props and renders them using each:

```
{#each recipients as email, index}
    <span bind:this={addressWidth}>
      <Address
      {email}
      />
    </span>
{/each}
```

I'm trying to get all the addresses widths by adding them to an array like this :

```
  $:{
    if(addressWidth) {
      arrayOfWidths = [...arrayOfWidths , addressWidth.offsetWidth];
         }
  }
```

However, with this method I always get an array with one element, the width of the last address in the each statement. How can I add all the widths to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the element to an index in the array:

```
{#each recipients as email, index}
    <span bind:this={addressWidth[index]}>
      <Address
        {email}
      />
    </span>
{/each}
```